# Create a map variable in dataweave script where key is from one list and value from another list

Tags: mule, dataweave

how can i create map variable in dataweave from 2 lists where the first element in first list should be the key in the map and first element from second list should be the value in the map and so on...

Below script is throwing error.

%dw 1.0
%output application/json
%var accountIdMap =  {
                     (payload.*accountIdList):
                     payload.*accountNameList
                    }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the order and number of elements in both lists are same, you should map on one list and then create elements -

`%var accountIdMap = (payload.accountIdList map ('$':payload.accountNameList($$)))`

$ = current element in iteration from accountIdList
$$ = index of current iteration from accountIdList. Get element at same index from other list.

Comment: I get the below errorCannot coerce a :array to a :function (com.mulesoft.weave.mule.exception.WeaveExecutionException). Message payload is of type: WeaveMessageProcessor$WeaveOutputHandler

Comment: My mistake ... Change it to payload.accountNameList[$$]